# Google Script - Macro to get data from a TABLE A and paste required values to Table B in sequence using LOOP

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I seek help in finalizing a MACRO script for following task.

Basic requirements is to get data from 'Ref' tab (around 200 symbols) in a sequence to 'Mcontrol'!E3 (this tab imports a table from the Website)

From this table, sorted highest 2 values of Symbol/s is extracted and exported to 'OI EOD' tab,
i.e. required value is shown in 'OI EOD'! G5:K5.

Then, copy paste range 'OI EOD'! G5:K5 , to the matched row (symbol match to 'Mcontrol'!E3) in the table below ('OI EOD'!C6:C210).

I seek help in putting forEach condition in the macro. SO that next cycle of copy paste function is completed, for each new value in Cell_1 reference.

Hope ppl take notice of the help request from a novice and give good solution and guidance.

Sheet link is Following
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1az2kas91KFxHcWhtWDg-g20hNYR-_zEiWPvYs-x42YU/edit?usp=sharing

Macro -

````
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1= wb.getSheetByName('Mcontrol');
  var sh2= wb.getSheetByName('OI EOD');
  var R1 = 3
  var C1 = 3
  var R2 = 3
  var C2 = 2
  var R3 = 3
  var C3 = 5
  var cell_1 = sh1.getRange(R1,C1).getValue();
  var cell_2 = sh1.getRange(R2,C2).getValue();
  var cell_3 = sh1.getRange(R3,C3).getValue();
   
  for(i=1;i<cell_2;i++);
  
  cell_1 = i + 1; 

  sh1.getRange(R1,C1).setValue(cell_1);{

    var Range_1 = sh2.getRange(6, 3, 300);
    var row_i = 5   ;              // source row no. for data copy paste
    const Row_1 = row_i;
    const Col_2 = 7;
    const Row_Offet1 = 1;
    const Col_Offet1 = 5;

    var data = Range_1.getValues();
    
    let ABC = cell_3;
    
    let row = 1 + data.findIndex(users => {return users[0] == ABC});  

    var row_target = row + row_i ;
    
    const sourceRange = sh2.getRange(Row_1,Col_2,Row_Offet1,Col_Offet1);
    
    var destRange = sh2.getRange(row_target,Col_2,Row_Offet1,Col_Offet1);

    sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
    
    for(k=1;k<cell_1.i;k++);   
  

    Logger.log(row_target);
    Logger.log(k) ;
    }
  //NEXT
    
    // cell_1=sh1.getRange(R1, C1);
    // sh1.getRange(R1,C1).setValue(i);
  }
}```

Thanks

Robin
````

Comment: If you mean to process all these 200+ 'symbols' with one loop I probably have the bad news to you. Google script has the time run quota 6 minutes (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). But every 'symbol' takes about 2—4 seconds to complete, as far as can tell. It will exceed the limit for sure. Probably only 50—100 'symbols' can be processed in one step. It's need a tricky workaround to automate this task. I can be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for your input Yuri. Cell_2 values can be manipulated accordingly for getting complete list is 2 or more parts. This value is  count of complete items of the list. Being a novice I could create 2 part working separately. 1st Change Ref. of web data import using For loop. 2nd extracting reqd. data and Copying it to respective row in 'OI EOD' sheet. Combining these 2 is getting mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if understand the task as a whole, so here is a guess.

This way you can get values from some `start` to some `end` 'symbols' (or numbers) and put these values in correct rows on the 'OI EOD' sheet:

```
function main() {
  var start = 1;
  var end = 5;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mcontrol_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Mcontrol');
  var oi_eod_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OI EOD');

  // get a list of all Symbols from column 'C' of the sheet 'OI EOD'
  var symbols = oi_eod_sheet.getRange('c6:c').getValues().flat();

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {

    // set the number i on the sheet 'Mcontrol' into the cell 'C3'
    mcontrol_sheet.getRange('c3').setValue(i);

    // wait to complete all the changes on the spreadsheet
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  
    // get the Symbol and Values from the range 'C5:K5' of the sheet 'OI EOD'
    var [symbl, _, _, _, ...values] = oi_eod_sheet.getRange('c5:k5').getValues()[0];


    // get the row index for this Symbol on the sheet 'Mcontrol'
    var row = symbols.indexOf(symbl) + 6;

    console.log({row}, {symbl}, {values});

    // set the values on the sheet 'OI EOD' on the row with given index
    oi_eod_sheet.getRange('g' + row + ':k' + row).setValues([values]);
  }
}
```

It's up to you to decide how the `start` and `end` values could be defined. It can be values from  two cells. Or it can be selected range. Or something else.

Comment: Very grateful Yuri. Simple and effective. In 6 min limit this function is able to fetch 60 symbols. That's very good. Can repeat 3-4 cycles to get all data. If you gets ideas for reducing this fetching time pl. do share. Appreciated .

Comment: It barely can be faster but there is the trick to save the counter into a script preferences (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) and continue the loop from last saved iteration after restarting a script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719626/script-automatic-continue-restart-after-timeout As far as I remember @Cooper had the ready solution, I failed to find it right now. Let me know if you really need it I can try to recreate it.